# How am I supposed to write a metafunction that works like the ones in MPL?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I seem to be missing something when trying to write a meta-function that calls into MPL code.  The follow code fails to compile with the following error on inst2, but works fine on inst1:

error C2903: 'apply' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template

```
using namespace boost::mpl;

template <typename VECTOR>
struct first_element : mpl::at_c<VECTOR, 0> {};

int main()
{
    typedef vector<
        vector<int, int>,
        vector<int, int>,
        vector<int, int>> lotso;

    typedef mpl::transform<lotso,
        first_element<_1>>::type inst1;

    typedef first_element<
        at_c<lotso,0>>::type inst2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you give the full error message including the template instantiation backtrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot a `::type` behind the call to `at_c` inside the typedef for `inst2`. Recall that your `first_element` expects something on which `at_c` can be applied. The raw `at_c<lotso, 0>`, however, is not yet evaluated. Evaluating a metafunction is done by adding `::type`.

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::mpl;

template <typename VECTOR>
struct first_element : mpl::at_c<VECTOR, 0> {};

int main()
{
    typedef vector<
        vector<int, int>,
        vector<int, int>,
        vector<int, int>> lotso;

    typedef mpl::transform<lotso,
        first_element<_1>>::type inst1;

    typedef first_element<
        at_c<lotso,0>::type >::type inst2;
                     ^^^^^^ <--- you forgot a ::type here

    static_assert(std::is_same<first_element<inst1>::type, inst2>::value, "bingo");

    return 0;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f852475761a6ec31b4bb3f617e7883ac-ad1704ff8e0d8d7b5f8f3873617fd98d). As a further check, I verified that a further dereference on `inst1` gives the same type as `inst2`.